# Why is my csv file separated by " \t " instead of commas (" , ")?

Tags: python, excel, csv

I downloaded data from internet and saved as a csv (comma delimited) file. The image shows what the file looks like in excel.

Using `csv.reader` in python, I printed each row. I have shown my code below along with the output in Spyder.

```
import csv

with open('p_dat.csv', 'r') as file:
    reader = csv.reader(file)
    for row in reader:
        print(row)
```

I am very confused as to why my values are not comma separated. Any help will be greatly appreciated.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Not sure what this has to do with python but it looks like you have a TSV (tab seperated) as opposed to a CSV

Comment: Open the ".csv" file with a text editor.. note that it is *not* "CSV". Adjust expectations / usages / exports appropriately.

Comment: Please don't post images of code, data, or Tracebacks. Copy and paste it as text then format it as code (select it and type `ctrl-k`)

Comment: Nowdays "CSV" means "character separated values", not "comma separated values". See the Wikipedia article on [CSV](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comma-separated_values).

Answer (score 5):

As pointed out in the comments, technically this is a TSV (tab-separated values) file, which is actually perfectly valid.

In practice, of course, not all libraries will make a "hard" distinction between a TSV and CSV file. The way you parse a TSV file is basically the same as the way you parse a CSV file, except that the delimiter is different.

There are actually multiple valid delimiters for this kind of file, such as tabs, commas, and semicolons. Which one you choose is honestly a matter of preference, not a "hard" technical limit.

Answer (score 0):

See [the specification for csvs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comma-separated_values#Specification). There are many options for the delimiter in the file. In this case you have a tab, `\t`.

The option is important. Suppose your data had commas in it, then a `,` as a delimiter would not be a good choice.

Comment: Your last point isn't exactly true. In this case, you'd just have to put quotes around that cell. (It gets a little ugly if the cell has both commas and quotes in it, though).

Comment: More appropriately these files that aren't using comma as the field delimiter should be called "Delimited Text File".  A true CSV is a Delimited Text File which uses a comma as the Field Delimiter and a Double-Quote as the Text Delimiter.  TSV uses Tab instead of Comma.  Concordance and Relativity (legal review databases) can use .DAT files which have ASCII 20 as the Field Delimiter and ASCII 254 as the Text Delimiter.  Many more such formats exist, some with additional Delimiters.

Answer (score 0):

Even though they're named comma-separated values, they're sometimes separated by different symbols (like the tab character that you have currently).

If you want to use Python to view this as a comma-separated file, you can try something like:

```
 import csv
...
        with open('p_dat.csv', 'r') as file:
            reader = csv.reader(file)
            for row in reader:
               commarow = row.replace("\t",",")
               print(commarow)
```

Comment: The `csv.reader` comes with a `delimiter` keyword-argument, so you can use that instead of manually replacing it in each row